# Where does the kinetic energy of a spaceship in flight go, when it is stopped by firing thrusters in the opposite direction?

Tags: energy

Where does the kinetic energy of a spaceship in flight go, when it is stopped by firing thrusters in the opposite direction?

If you stopp a driving car, the kinetic energy is converted to thermal energy in the brakes, tires, air.

But where does the kinetic energy of a spaceship go, when it is stopped by firing thrusters in the opposite direction of travel.

I do understand, that the energy expenditure of the braking process is the same, as the energy expenditure that was needed for the acceleration in the first place...

But this makes it even more weird... sort of? Where does the kinetic energy go? Why can it not be reused, like in a hybrid/electric car? Or ist there just no way yet?

Comment: Does the wikipedia article on spacecraft propulsion answer your question?

Comment: You have to emit something to break in space and the emitted object carries the kinetic energy in form of linear momentum.

Answer (score 2):

The kinetic energy of the spacecraft is carried off by the exhaust gas from the rocket engines that are being fired to stop its motion.

Comment: Thank you! So that would mean, the sum of particles fired while braking the spaceship have the energy of the fuel used + the kinetic energy of the spaceship? 

Or in other words: If you are in the way of the exhaust plume of a starting rocket you get less fried, than when you are in the exhaust plume of a braking rocket?